# How to set up X11 forwarding in byobu inside a LXC container

Tags: ssh, xorg, lxc, byobu

I currently SSH into a LXC container running in a Ubuntu host machine. I have managed to set up X11 forwarding from the container to my local machine but when I start byobu (inside the container) the X11 forwarding stops working (`$DISPLAY` is not assigned a value).

I have tried looking into byobu's configuration and manually changing display to the same value as it is in the container before entering byobu (`localhost:10:0`) to no avail.

Any ideas how to set up this X11 forwarding from byobu? Thanks.